# How does Marty Byrde intend to turn this person and why would they refuse?

Tags: plot-explanation, ozark

In season 3, Marty Byrde saves his life by telling Navarro that he can turn an FBI agent to work for the cartel. He is referring to agent Maya Miller.

In order to turn her, it looks like Marty's plan is to feed her ilegally obtained information, that she would not be able to get any other way, about scammers, which is something she cares about deeply. She repeatedly refuses to take this information, as she doesn't want to compromise her principles. This complicates Marty's plan to turn her.

- **How would Marty be able to use this information to turn her?** Was the plan to eventually tell her "I'm not going to turn myself in, but you can keep getting these tips and make the world a better place if you just let me be. Otherwise, you won't have these tips and I won't surrender either way"? Was his plan all along that she would not take the tips and her superiors would, so they would reprimand her and she would feel disillusioned with the FBI?
- **Why would taking these tips be a compromise to her principles?** Her superiors are happy to take this information from the "anonymous source", and are not the least worried when she tells them the "anonymous source" is Marty Byrde. Does she think she would not be making the world a better place but instead helping the Navarro cartel (as she might think that Marty has ulterior motives to give her that information)? Does she think that Marty is trying to clean his conscience without paying the price (testifying and going to jail) and is trying to get him to break by refusing to let him do it?